# How do you vertically align text in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

How do you vertically align text in Bootstrap 5?  There are answers for Bootstrap 4 but none for Bootstrap 5.

Comment: Know more about new bootstrap release you can refer https://codeaccuracy.blogspot.com/2020/08/whats-new-in-bootstrap-5.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there is a default method built-in, link [here](https://v5.getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/vertical-align/). As a demo:

```html
<div>
  <span class="align-middle">middle</span>
</div>
```